# How to set the position of a button after animation?

Tags: android, animation, position, clickable

I have a button (placed in a linearlayout) with animation. After the animation is completed (simple translateAnimation) I want that animated button to be enabled. I realized that using an animation only has an effect for the button drawable, so the clickable "place" stays at the original position.

```
layout= (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.newitemtext);
 layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_box);
btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btn);
 moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0,0 , 0, 200);
            moveLefttoRight.setDuration(1000);
            moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true); 


            animbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    layout.startAnimation(moveLefttoRight);
                    layout.setEnabled(true);


                }
            });

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("TAG", "CCIK");


                }


});
```

The btn button is in the LinearLayout layout. How could I set the position after the animation? I tried to use setPadding but with no success. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Place it correctly from the beginning (but invisible/gone) and start the animation (& make it visible) so it goes *from* where you want the button to appear and ends up where the button is actually already at?

Comment: That is not possible in my case :) Anyway nice workaround :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`View.setLayoutParams()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29), to update a Views params - note that it depends on what kind of layout the view is inside as to how the params can be updated. For example, if your view is in a `LinearLayout`, then you will only be able to adjust params that relate to a `LinearLayout` (gravity, weight, width, height, etc.) so you would not be able to adjust the absolute X/Y coords. You may want to switch to something like a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) to try and move the view to the final destination based on the location of other views.